# Registering and using an ActiveX / COM component that is created with an IDL with the UUIDs generated at runtime

Tags: c++, com, activex, uuid, typelib

I have an existing ActiveX / COM component that has been working well for some time now. This ActiveX component was initially designed to be used by one client application per machine. However, now there is a need to extend this ActiveX component to be used by more than 1 client application in the same PC.

I know that the very reason why COM is in place is re-usability and that there are ways to manage this, such as reference count etc. However my issue is different. Please read on...

Every client application of mine if different, and these client applications act as standalone applications - in the sense that they are installed and uninstalled as individual applications. They each carry a copy of this ActiveX component and install it in it's own installation directory. Every client app has it's own copy of this ActiveX component that it installs, uses and uninstalls.

Given below are the steps of what basically happens. Step 4 below is the actual Issue:

1. The first time I install a client application X, since it uses COM, the installer registers the COM component and this creates an entry a "typelib" entry in the registry with the UUID as defined in the IDL and .rgs.
2. If I install another client app Y, before uninstalling client app X, the installer of the Y updates the "typelib"'s "win32" value with the the path to the ActiveX component in Y's current directory.
3. When I uninstall the client application X, it removes this typelib entry from registry.
4. So at this point if I try to uninstall app Y, it fails because the typelib entry is missing. X's uninstaller has already removed this entry.

To resolve this issue, I am trying to bypass using type libraries or use alternate ways (if possible) to use an ActiveX component without the issue I am facing now.

The issue has come down to this - To have different typelibrary entries for different client applications, but for the same ActiveX component.

Can someone guide me and suggest a good, elegant solution?

Comment: One solution might be to use registration-free COM: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx

Comment: @Paolo: Thanks! That is certainly an option I am working on now. Any pointers on how to go about it?

Answer (score -1):

I have solved this issue by creating the IDL by modifying the rgs file.